# Dominos arrangement (Java Coding)

Tags: java

I am trying to use Java to solve the following.

Given an arrangement of dominos, determine, whether or not it is a legal arrangement and return True or False accordingly. 
For example, this is an illegal arrangement 
[2 3][4 2][2 2][3 5] 
and this is a legal arrangement of Dominos. 
[2 3][3 5][5 4][4 5].

I have no clue how to begin this to write this program.

Comment: How would you determine by hand, if an arrangement is legal or not?

Comment: Try google before posting on stack overflow.

Comment: An arrangement of dominoes could be represented with different datatypes, pick one you're familiar with : an array of arrays of integers, an array of integers, a List<List<Integer>>, a List<Integer>, a List<Domino> where you code your own Domino class.

Comment: I tried googling this multiple times, but I didn't find anything. I need help starting the program. I understand that I need to create array(s) and some how say when it is true and when it is false, but I don't know how to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a Domino class

```
public class Domino {
    private int leftValue;
    private int rightValue;

    public Domino(int leftValue, int rightValue) {
        this.leftValue = leftValue;
        this.rightValue = rightValue;
    }

    public int getLeftValue() {
        return leftValue;
    }

    public int getRightValue() {
        return rightValue;
    }
}
```

Create an array or list containing the domino's

```
Domino[] dominos = new Domino[] {
            new Domino(2, 3),
            new Domino(3, 2),
            new Domino(2, 5),
            new Domino(2, 5)
        };
```

Loop and match left and right values

```
    Domino previous = null;
    for (Domino current : dominos) {
       if (previous != null) {
          if (current.getLeftValue() != previous.getRightValue()) {
             throw new Exception("Illegal arrangement detected");
          }
       }
       previous = current;
    }
```